# Match words as single hit

Tags: regex

I have string like this:

> dog dog maddog

Also I have following regex:

```
[dog]*
```

Now, this matches dog dog ddog. I would like to get rid of extra d, and hopefully keep hit as 1xdog dog dog instead of 3xdog.

Am I missing something, or this look a bit tricky to do?

edit: to explain a bit better, I'm not sure if this is just difficult or am missing something. (dog)* would produce 2 hits: dog dog, and second hit is dog (from last string). I would like just one hit dog dog dog. regexpal, for example, highlights what is hit by regex.

edit2: Basically what I'm asking if you must use [dog]* (note must), how do you get rid of extra d ?

Comment: Why did you think you needed brackets there?

Comment: Did you mean `(dog)*`? (normal brackets, not square brackets)

Comment: point is to get hit 1x dog dog dog, not 3xdog

Comment: what does this even mean? `hit 1x dog dog dog, not 3xdog` what do you mean with hit?

Comment: (dog)* matches dog dog and dog(2 hits). if you use regex pal or something like that, it marks colors around hits. e.x. in regex pal everything should be yellow, to indicate one hit

Comment: As @stema (and others) have mentioned, you're using square brackets incorrectly.  Also, your use of the word _hit_ is doing nothing but confusing people. It also sounds like _regex pal_ is misleading you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your square brackets you are creating a character class. That means `[dog]` will match any character from inside the brackets. The `*` makes it match 0 or more times one of those characters. Because of that it does match "ddog". It would also match on "good" or "ggddo".

Comment: yeah, i would also think that regex pal may misleading me a bit, question probably doesnt make any sense